# Entity Framework Core: FOREIGN KEY may cause cycles error in a migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I have Manufacture and Photo classes. I want to store "Logo" (Photo) and "Cover" (Photo) properties in Manufacture class. But when I try to add-migration, it gives me the below error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Manufactures_Photos_LogoId' on table 'Manufactures' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

How should I fix this?

Class Manufacture:

```cs
public class Manufacture : BaseEntity
{
    public Manufacture()
    {
        Logo = new Photo();
        CoverPhoto = new Photo();
        SocialMediaAccounts = new List<SocialMediaAccount>();
        Group = new Group();
    }   
    public Photo Logo { get; set; }
    public int LogoId { get; set; }
    public Photo CoverPhoto { get; set; }
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public int GroupId { get; set; }
    public Group Group { get; set; }
    public string? Website { get; set; }
    public List<SocialMediaAccount> SocialMediaAccounts { get; set; } = new List<SocialMediaAccount>();
}
```

class Photo:

```
public class Photo:BaseEntity
{
    public string? Url { get; set; }
}
```

class BaseEntity for any extra info:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObjectCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ObjecLastModifiedDate { get; set; }
    private ICollection<INotification> domainEvents;
    public ICollection<INotification> DomainEvents => domainEvents;
    public void AddDomainEvents(INotification notification)
    {
        domainEvents ??= new List<INotification>();
        domainEvents.Add(notification);
    }
}
```

I designed tables like this before, but I do not find what is the problem.

Comment: can you show SocialMediaAccount

Comment: public class SocialMediaAccount : BaseEntity
    {
        public SocialMediaAccount()
        {
            SocialPlatform = new SocialPlatform();     
        }
        public int SocialPlatformId { get; set; }
        public SocialPlatform? SocialPlatform { get; set; }
        public string? Url { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: public class SocialPlatform:BaseEntity
    {
        public SocialPlatform()
        {
            Logo = new Photo();
        }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Photo Logo { get; set; }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two releation from the Manufacture table to the photo table(logo,CoverPhoto), which defaults to the Cascade delete type
You have two ways to solve this

1.change type Cascade delete  one of classes

In DbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      modelBuilder.Entity<Manufacture>()       
    .HasOne(u => u.Logo)
    .WithOne()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

Cascade - dependents should be deleted
Restrict - dependents are unaffected
SetNull - the foreign key values in dependent rows should update to NULL

[EF Core OnDelete](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method)

2. one of the class that can be nullable